# Show that if $(s_n)$ is a sequence in $S$ that converges in $S$, then $(d(s_n,t))$ converges in $\Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(S,d)$ be a metric space and $t \in S$. Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence in $(S,d)$. Show that if $(s_n)$ converges in $S$, then $(d(s_n,t))$ converges in $\Bbb R$.

If $s_n \to t$, then $d(s_n,t) \to 0 \in \Bbb R$. Suppose $s_n \to s \ne t$ where $s \in S$.
By the Triangle Inequality,
$$0 \le d(s_n,t) \le d(s_n,s) + d(s,t).$$
What's next? How can $d(s,t)$ approach to be zero for which $d(s_n,t) \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$?
Any ideas and help? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: $|d(s_n,t)-d(s,t)| \leq d(s_n,s)$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Since $d(s_n,s) \to 0$, then $d(s_n,t) \to d(s,t)$? But, is $d(s,t) \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But, is $d(s,t) \in \Bbb R$, Sir?

Comment: By defintion of a metric, $d(s,t)$ is a real number.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Aaah, I see. Okay, thanks for your help, Sir.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Once again, please, Sir. Am I true that we must considered two case like above, i.e., for $t$ and $s \ne t$?

Comment: No. There is no need for that.